# How to edit the HTML contatined by do_action( 'woocommerce_cart_collaterals' ) hook in woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm doing woocommerce custom coding, trying to change the regular template provided by woocommerce in order to fit my specifications.

Basically, I want to edit the HTML contained in the `do_action( 'woocommerce_cart_collaterals' );` as shown in the following code and image below

```
<div class="tb-cart-total">

                <?php
                    /**
                     * Cart collaterals hook.
                     *
                     * @hooked woocommerce_cross_sell_display
                     * @hooked woocommerce_cart_totals - 10
                     */
                    do_action( 'woocommerce_cart_collaterals' );
                ?>

            </div>
```

[image: Looking to edit the HTML in this section]

So the question is as simple as, how can I access the HTML in that section? Or Where is the hook referenced from? How can I get the real HTML of that area so that I can edit it?

Answer (score 0):

I was needed it too but can't find on the web. By the way here it is;

At WooCommerce template:

```
/woocommerce/templates/cart/cart-totals.php
```

At your theme (this file may not be included):

```
/woocommerce/cart/cart-totals.php
```